# Javascript parent and child window functions

Tags: javascript

function myFunction(){

```
myWin = open("","","width=200,height=200");

with(myWin.document){
  open();
  write("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Child Window</TITLE>");
  write("<SCRIPT>function myTest(){");
  write("alert('This function is defined in the child window ");
  write("and is called from the parent window.'); this.focus();}");
  write("</SCRIPT></HEAD><BODY><H3>Child Window</H3><HR>");
  write("<FORM><INPUT TYPE='button' VALUE='parent window function' ");

        write("onClick='opener.winFunction();'>");                                            
   write("<P><INPUT TYPE='button' VALUE='close window' ");
   write("onClick='window.close();'>");
   write("</FORM></BODY></HTML>");
   close();
 }
}

function winFunction(){
    alert("This function is defined in the parent window\n" +
          "and is called from the child window.");
    myWin.focus();
}
```

//-->

To explain further what my initial query was, the code above, should open the child window (myWin) with the second button, the 'Open child window' button without the need to open the window with the first button or do anything else. It should simply call the myWin.myTest()function The child window will open when the second button is pressed but needs to have the child window open first (first button push) before it'll work. This is not the intended purpose, the 'Open child window' button should work without anything else needing to be done. For some reason the parent window isn't communicating with the myWin window and myTest function. It's not homework, it's part of a certification course lab and is coded in the manner I have been shown to understand as correct. DTD isn't included as the focus is the JavaScript. I code correctly with regards to that and other W3C requirements.

Comment: Problem is: Code is.... no I will get banned for such a word, let alone the use of `with` disqualifies this question :(

Comment: Why do you even bother declaring a doctype if you are not going to use valid HTML 4.0 Transitional markup?

Comment: Sorry can't help you. My eyes started bleeding after seeing this code.

Comment: The saddest part is that this seems to be a school homework. This is type of stuff schools teach students? Using with() and wrapping javascript code with `<!--  -->`?

Comment: Worse than wrapping the code with `<!--` and `-->`, the opening comment is prefixed with a JS comment — which largely defeats the object (which is to hide the content of the element from browsers, like Netscape 2, which don't recognize the script element).

Comment: Everything works fine there for me, except if you I call a function of the other window if the other window is not there. Tested in FF and IE6

Comment: The Doctype (HTML 4.0 (also without the bug fixes from 4.01) without a URI) also triggers quirks mode, IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

I redid the code slightly nicer. It works as intended here. Apart from referencing the correct window object directly it isn't that much different.

The code still looks ugly, create new windows with urls rather then like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/B8rDN/24/

Comment: You need to remove 'var' from `win` so the event listener can access it.  http://jsfiddle.net/B8rDN/25/

Comment: Forgot to undo that. i hoped var would have mapped to global space.

Comment: The point of the `var` keyword is so a variable is mapped to local space.

Comment: No, it's not homework nor am I a child!. I am a cert student who was taught to raw code in this manner through CIW . I asked for help, not to be patronised. Thought I'd get guidance not a barrage of third party insults. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @MikeThornley I strongly advice againts using document.write and with, and eval. I do not meant to be patronising but that code looks like its copy and pasted right out of 1998. If the rest of the things you are taught are like _this_ then I advice you to find a different course.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine (*although i escaped the `/` of the closing tags in the string and made the `\/`*)

demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4FBZv/

Comment: Raynos, well thanks for the advice but surely I could just read up and learn a different practice with coding?. My JavaScript works, yet might be not quite up to spec, so I'm sure I can tailor it to be more modern with practice?. I'm hoping what I have learnt so far hasn't been a waste as it's a battle grasping the language!. This section is fundamental JavaScript and my learning continues from here really so I'll read up and source alternative code schemes. Thank you.

Comment: You want some real advice. Find a copy in the library and read http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101992 then read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide And pick up a copy of crockfords the good parts if you really want to get going. Javascript has a lot of _bad_ books and _bad_ guides.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll check them out, Raynos!.

Comment: Raynos, Just bought the O'reilly comprehensive guide online and funnily enough going back to using vars as recommended, instead of with().. I noticed this: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/ simple adjustment and now adopt the practice to my coding. I just didn't know but thanks, all.